# How do I have scala actors reporting task completion?

Tags: scala, actor

I need to chop a series of remote calls into chunks. I thought of using actors.

I thought of something like this:

```
class ControlActor() extends Actor{
  var counter = 1000
  def act{
     for (i <- 1 until 1000) { new RequestActor(this) start }
    while(true){
      receive{
        case "Stop" =>{counter = counter-1; if(counter==0){return}}
      }
    } 
  }
}

class RequestActor(parent:ControlActor) extends actor{ ... }
```

but this has an obvious problem: when I get into the recieve block, some RequestActor instances may already have finished executed. What happens if they send a message to an actor that is not yet on a message recieving state? does the message get queued or is it discarded?

Most important: **how do I create child actors that are able to notify the actor that created them, even if they return very fast?**

Also related: Is it a good practice to pass the current actor instance (`this`) to other actors? For some reason I haven't seen anybody doing it.

Comment: As I tell everyone using Scala actor questions, check out Akka. It has a very high concentration of awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're perfectly fine; unprocessed messages in an actor will simply go into the mailbox and be processed when the actor is ready for them.  However, with regards to actors replying to their callers, you generally don't need to pass a reference to `this`, because actors can communicate directly to their caller with `reply`.  Here's a simple example:

```
class MyActor(n: Int) extends Actor {
  def act() {
    loop {
      react {
        case m: Int => reply(n + m)  // Use `reply` to reply to caller
      }
    }
  }
}

// new MyActor(0), new MyActor(10), new MyActor(20), ...
val actors = (0 to 100 by 10) map (new MyActor(_).start())

// Message each actor with '5', expecting a response (that's what `!?` does)
val responses = actors map (_ !? 5)
responses foreach println
```

results in

```
5
15
25
35
45
55
65
75
85
95
105
```

The `!?` operator, however, will block the main thread until we get the reply to its message.  As a result, `actors map (_ !? 5)` isn't actually all that concurrent.  Instead, you can use `!!` to generate futures (which you can let compute in the meantime and defer evaluation of until you're ready).  So... changing those last two lines to

```
val futures = actors map (_ !! 5)
futures foreach (future => println(future()))
```

will message the first actor with '5', giving me a future to hold onto in the meantime, and then message the the second actor with '5', giving me a future to hold onto in the meantime, etc., and, when we're ready, we can evaluate the future (`future()`) and use its result in some way (like printing it out).

Answer (score 1):

As long as an actor has been started, messages sent to it will be queued for the next receive/react call.

Passing actors via the constructor is also fine, but you should pass them as Actor instead of the derived type, to remove the temptation of accessing the actor's state directly.

You don't normally see this because usually actors are passed along in messages. But there is nothing wrong with what you are doing.